# the difference between sub-system and additive composition component in UML component diagram

Tags: components, uml, component-diagram

I am trying to understand the difference between these two concepts:

For subSystem, I have found a website: https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-component-diagram/

[image]

For the additive composition, on this website: https://cpentalk.com/618/illustrate-composition-hierarchical-composition-composition

people said

[image: "Additive composition: we put (add) two or more components together to create a new component which combines their functionality. If A and B are two components, then the new component is a combination of the corresponding interfaces of A and B. A and B are not dependent and do not call each other, only the functionality is combined to create a new component."]

In the `OnlineStore` subsystem example, because `OrderSystem` component is calling the `Catalogue` component.  For it to be an additive composition, should all the component inside be independent?

[image]

Can I say my example above is the additive composition because `profile` and `bank_account` are independent?  I basically use some `glueCode` to combine their interface together so there is no component are dependent.  Do you think it is a good example of the additive composition?

Comment: _People said_ is what the cross is about. There is no term _additive composition_ in UML. So _people_ defined it and it may mean what it will.

Answer (score 0):

### Subsystems and components

The UML defines the subsystem as a subpart of the system:

> A unit of hierarchical decomposition for large systems. A subsystem is commonly instantiated indirectly. Definitions of subsystems vary widely among domains and methods, and it is expected that domain and method profiles will specialize this construct.

The UML defines a component as an autonomous subpart of the system/subsystem:

> Component can always be considered an autonomous unit within a system or subsystem. (...) 
> A Component is a self-contained unit (...)
>  A Component is a substituable unit that can be replaced at design time or run-time by a Component that offers equivalent functionality based on compatibility of its Interfaces.

The subsystem is itself a component. So subsystem and component represent the same kind of reality.  It's just subtle differences in the wording:  *subsystem* is mainly used for decomposing larger systems in smaller parts, whereas *component* is often used for assembling smaller pieces in more complex parts. SO the different terms just suggest different levels of decomposition/scale in larger systems.

### Component composition in UML

There are multiple ways of composing components to assemble more complex ones.  UML does not define anything in this area. Your definition for *additive composition* seems to correspond to a juxtaposition: the two components are kept unrelated and offer their services to the outside world, as if they were separate components.

Unfortunately, your diagram is ambiguous in that regard:  We don’t know for sure if the glue just forwards the behavior or if it transforms or combines it. We don’t even know if it’s the same interface, since the interface has a different name (the methods having the same name can be pure coincidence).

Accordingly, you should better provide the original interfaces to the outside world via a port and delegation connectors (example [here](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html)):

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I agree with most of the answer. However, there is a problem in the diagram. The UML 2.5.1 says: _"[...] simple Ports (Ports with a single required or provided Interface)[...]. When connecting simple Ports, normal Connector notation for assembly or delegation may be shown connected to the ball or socket symbol rather than to the Port symbol itself."_ Since you have a complex port and the sub components don't have ports, you must connect directly to the sub components. Also the sub components must be parts, in which case there would be a colon in front of their names.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer Thanks foor this review.  Better like this ?

Comment: Yes, this is better. Except for the port on the upper border. It is not simple, so it should not have connectors graphically connected to the lolli. However, I think in this case, there is no ambiguity, since these are delegation connectors and the opposite ports are simple. Still, according to the rules, it is not formally correct.